# how to package a project mixing with Java and Python

Tags: java, python, package

My project is written by both Java and Python.
I wonder there is any tool that can package Python code to Java war file? 
Basically my java code will be compiled to a war file, and python code are packaged in a few of egg files then be put into classes/ folder of war file.
Now I am using a python script which calls maven to build war file, calls setup.py to build egg files, and combines them at last.
This way is not scale as I have to modify the script every time I have some new egg files. 
Does anybody know a good tool for this kind of things?
thank you

Comment: I don't think long build times means that a solution doesn't scale.

Comment: no. the 'not scale' I meant was not for performance. It actually means 'not productive' in development process as you have to modify build script frequently to package new components, and most of these effort is duplicated which should be taken care by some package system